# High quality screen capture

Tags: html, resolution, photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I'm making a manual for a web-based app. I take screenshots and put them into adobe illustrator and they lose their quality extremely fast when zooming in. Is there anyway I can take high resolution or vector based screenshots that don't loose image quality when zoomed in? This seems to be only a problem with illustrator, with photoshop when I zoom in it gets slightly fuzzy but thats it.

Comment: The quality of the screenshot directly depends on your monitors resolution, i.e. bigger monitor = higher resolution. I don't believe there is anything you can do about that.

Comment: photoshop is probably doing a better job at interpolating the pixels of your screenshot or illustrator just don't alter your original image on purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no exact way to capture as a vector. Because of the capture program, not knowing of any geometry shapes.

Although, you can capture a raster image and convert it to a [vector](https://www.google.com/search?q=raster%20to%20vector). There are numerous tools out there, that will allow you to do this conversion. Then you will have to do a little bit of tweaking. But in reality you cannot take a capture as a vector, or convert it and have it be "pixel-perfect".

Hope this helps!

Zachary